# Does MSVC 2017 support automatic CPU dispatch?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-optimization, cpu-architecture, avx, auto-vectorization

I read on a few sites that MSVC can actually emit say AVX instructions, when SSE2 architecture is used and detect the AVX support runtime. Is it true?

I tested various loops that would definitely benefit from AVX/AVX2 support, but when run in debugger I couldn't really find any AVX instructions.

When /arch:AVX is used, then it emits AVX instructions, but it of course crashes on CPUs that doesn't support it (tested), so no runtime detection either. I could use AVX intrinsics though and it would successfully create AVX instructions from them. Any ideas?

Comment: Last I checked, it's a *bad* idea to use AVX intrinsics without `/arch:AVX` for that compilation unit, in MSVC.  You can get code that causes SSE/AVX transition penalties, because it will use non-VEX encodings for any instructions it can even in a function that has VEX instructions.  [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41303780)

Comment: I'm using VZEROUPPER. Anyways that's not question - I'm mostly interested in whether MSVC can actually compile C++ loops into AVX (and higher instruction sets) code in /arch:sse2 with runtime checking.

Comment: Right, but you're only using `vzeroupper` at the end of your function, I'd guess.  I meant that MSVC without `/arch:AVX` can mix SSE and VEX inside a single function.  e.g. consider doing a horizontal sum with `_mm256_extractf128_ps` down to a `__m128`, so you're using some 128-bit intrinsics like `_mm_add_ps`.  Those will use non-VEX encoding, and mixing those with VEX coded shuffles like `vpermilps`, or some more `_mm256_add_ps`, will be catastrophic for performance on Haswell.

Comment: In the beginning too... Anyways normally I'm actually compiling it with /arch:AVX and detecting AVX support manually. But AGAIN, that's not the question here... "I'm mostly interested in whether MSVC can actually compile C++ loops into AVX (and higher instruction sets) code in /arch:sse2 with runtime checking." By that I also assume it would be smart enough to zero the high ymm regs whenever needed.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm commenting about the dangerous idea in your last sentence in the last paragraph, instead of posting it as an answer.  I don't use MSVC other than sometimes looking at its asm output or checking if something compiles with it, on http://godbolt.org/.  But anyway, no, MSVC is *not* that smart, and just blindly emits horrible code with transition penalties last I checked, if you use AVX intrinsics without `/arch:AVX`.

Comment: Probably with intrinsics it may not be ideal. But with pure C++ code, that's the main question. I use intrinsics only in extreme cases.

Comment: I know that's not the main question.  But your post still says "I could use AVX intrinsics though and it would successfully create AVX instructions from them."  If your definition of success includes avoiding SSE/AVX transition penalties, then no, that's not a safe option.  Please correct that sentence, then your question is fine (although I think the answer is a simple no: AFAIK MSVC doesn't auto-vectorize for multiple instruction sets with automatic runtime dispatching the way ICC will, or [even gcc with target clones](//stackoverflow.com/q/44479069).)

Comment: Related: [VC++ /arch:AVX option – unsafe at any speed](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/vc-archavx-option-unsafe-at-any-speed/) says it's hard to get runtime CPU dispatching to work totally safely on MSVC.

Comment: Hmm, maybe MSVC isn't as bad as it used to be.  https://godbolt.org/g/dWbZXq shows CL19 using `vaddps   xmm3, xmm3, xmm0` for `_mm_add_ps` in a function that used 256-bit intrinsics.  I thought I remembered seeing a problem on Godbolt CL19, but maybe it's more subtle or maybe I'm misremembering.  Maybe only after inlining?

Comment: Any of [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) check first whether AVX2 is supported, if not check whether SSE2 is supported, and if not, it will resort to good ol' `cmp/jne`. But I think Microsoft has implemented them in assembly. There is a couple of bug reports([1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166375/avx-instructions-generated-since-155-update.html), [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/04/29/visual-studio-2015-rc-now-available/)) that show MSVC generates AVX without checking for support.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think MS did quite some work on it lately. I recently benchmarked Intel vs. MSVC vs. CLANG, and while Intel was microscopically ahead, it took like 5x time to compile and resulting executables were like 4x larger, plus unreliable. CLANG was worse in performance by several percents so...

Comment: @HadiBrais these bug reports are sort of what I found too. Anyways I tried on nonAVX2 CPU with /arch:AVX and it seems working fine using the newest MSVC. As for checking manually - yes I'm doing that too, but only for the most relevant algorithms, it's quite a pain to provide multiple implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted the VC++ team, and the answer is "no". The bug reports linked in the comments under the question show only normal bugs, rather than bugs in the auto-dispatch code generator.

So if /arch:SSE2 is specified (by default), VC++ can only auto-dispatch to SSE4. This is the only form of auto-dispatching that is currently supported. In other words, VC++ cannot auto-dispatch to AVX/AVX2.