# Compiling same class defined in header in cpp files compiled against multiple architectures

Tags: c++, compilation, dispatch

Let's say I've defined a class like so:

```
#include <vector>

enum class cpu { sse2, sse4, avx, avx4 };

template <cpu architecture = current_cpu>
class foo // current_cpu defined based on compiler's target architecture
{
    std::vector<int> data_;

public:
    // methods...
};
```

I compile this 4 times for each of the target architectures (sse2, sse4, avx, avx2) for x86_64.

This generates 4 different classes `foo<cpu::sse2>`, `foo<cpu::sse4>`, etc

I then use some runtime dispatching to create the correct version at runtime and use some pointer trickery to invoke the methods on the instance in memory.

The question is related to the `std::vector<int> _data`. **Can the compiler decide not to inline all of `std::vector` so that the linker is left with several versions of, say, a std::vector method compiled for multiple architectures and then link to the wrong one because they all have the same mangled name?**

Comment: I wonder how the compiler would even compile `std::vector` for several architectures.  I believe it will only compile it for the architecture you compile the code for.

Comment: Neat question! This is pedantic, but consider adding a `template <...>` declaration above your struct before a bunch of people come running 'round telling you that your code isn't valid C++.

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning

Comment: @parktomatomi - well spotted thanks :-)

Comment: @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica - the class will be compiled four times for different architectures.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl - is there an equivalent for MSVC? (p.s. not sure it answers the question, but it's an interesting point :-))

Comment: This document mentions that when CPU dispatching is used, there is a suffix added to mangled function names to distinguish them on the Itanium ABI used by g++ and clang: https://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf . This other SO answer mentions that MSVC only supports limited CPU dispatch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846979/does-msvc-2017-support-automatic-cpu-dispatch

Comment: @keith I don't know about MSVC, but I'd look that up if I were you :)

Answer (score 0):

On Clang, `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` in theory could be used, however it doesn't seem to be working in practice. The alternative is to avoid classes/functions that do not make themselves unique to different architectures.